# How use AntWeb API in Swift

Tags: swift, api

I have experience in OpenWeather API and think that other API's almost the same. But not.

AntWeb provide open API and tell a little bit how to use it.
https://www.antweb.org/api.do

But their example-links doesn't returns any data in JSON. I found only Python examples (or other programming language, idk), on GitHub.

Is it some special API or am I missing something?
Or it doesn't work at all?

I was try simple `URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url)`. But it returns nothing.

```
   let url = URL(string: "https://antweb.org/v3.1/geoSpecimens?coords=37,%20-122&limit=100&radius=1")!

   let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
      guard let data = data else { return }
      print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
   }

   task.resume()
```

Comment: According to the linked page they are using json. I tried and clicked some of the example links/queries but I got only blank pages so it looks like something is wrong on their side. All in all I don’t see how this is a question for stackoverflow, try contacting the publisher instead.

Comment: Thanks. I got it. I now how to use json. I thought maybe it was some kind of unusual API. Already sent them an email, but they haven't responded yet. Waiting...